# How can I dynamically create span in javascript by class name (that already exist and styled in html, that called span class= "bullet")

Tags: javascript

Here is where I try to create span, inside my tables td

```
const oneTd = document.createElement('td');
if(result == 1){
var span = document.createElement('bullet');
oneTd.appendChild(span);
}
```

And here is my span class in html

```
    <span class="bullet">
    <div class="bra"></div>
    <div class="crr"></div>
    </span>
```

When I use querySelector, it works but only once, but I need to append it each time result ==1

```
const oneTd = document.createElement('td');
if(result == 1){
    const bul = document.querySelector(".bullet");
    oneTd.appendChild(bul);

}
```

Comment: "document.createElement('bullet')", surely you mean `"SPAN"`, because there is no element bullet in HTML, it's your class name, so you need to add it to your span element after creating it and then append it to whatever you want

Comment: @SaymoinSam, like this: const span = document.createElement('span');
        oneTd.appendChild(span);

Comment: how o I add class?

Comment: like this `span.className = "bullet"`;

Comment: el.classList.add('className');

Comment: I did like this but still doesn't workconst span = document.createElement('span');
        span.classList.add('bullet');
        oneTd.appendChild(span);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example to add a span element with predefined styles to the body element using `.innerHTML` property each time the user presses the button

```js
function addSpan() {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<span class="bullet"></span> ';
}
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.bullet {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addSpan()">Add Span</button><br>
```

Comment: But how to do it dynamically in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
    const oneTd = document.createElement('td');
    function addEl() {
      if(result === 1){
        const span = document.createElement('span');
        span.classList.add('bullet');
        oneTd.appendChild(span);
      }
    }
```

and as a result you will have

```
<td><span class="span"></span></td>
```

Comment: hmm, need more details, how you run this code? what is the var `result`? do you append this tag `oneTd` ?

Comment: each time when you run addEl() function it will add new tag span into oneTd

Comment: I guess its something with css, because when I inspect span element is created